# nginx - self-signed certificate signed by a self signed root ca is not accepted

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, certificate-authority

I want to set up a CA for my local network. The root certificate should be installed on various devices (iPhone, Windows PC, MacBook). With a server certificate I want to secure the traffic between browser and webserver (nginx 1.17 on debian 10.1 as reverse proxy).

I created the root certificate with the following commands:

```
# key
openssl genrsa -des3 -out rootCA.key 4096

# root-certificate
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 1024 -out rootCA.crt
```

Then I created a CSR for a specific server:

```
# key
openssl genrsa -out myserver.local.key 2048

# csr
openssl req -new -key myserver.local.key -out myserver.local.csr
```

Finally I created the server certificate with the root key:

```
openssl x509 -req -in myserver.local.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out myserver.local.crt -days 500 -sha256
```

In the configuration for the nginx webserver I have added the following entries:

```
lists 443 ssl;
server_name myserver.local;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificates/myserver.local/myserver.local.crt;
ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/certificates/myserver.local/myserver.local.key;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;
```

I installed the root certificate on an iOS (version 13) device and then accepted the certificate in the settings (Settings - General - Profile).

After restarting the server I still get a hint that the certificate is not trusted. Unfortunately, iOS doesn't give me detailed information, so I can't find a clue where to start troubleshooting. On MacOS with Chrome and Safari, I also get an error message. Here, too, I imported the root certificate into the keychain.

Does anyone have a hint about what's wrong here?

Comment: Your CA is probably missing the `CA: true` constraint among other things. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27931596/4862445) for more.

Comment: Here is the result after executing `openssl s_client` (before submitting I have installed the root-cert in /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ and ran sudo update-ca-certificates): https://gist.github.com/janhuddel/a09d3784b2a1530eeafe821e9105dac4

Comment: @RichardSmith No. I' have verified the CA cert with `openssl x509 -in rootCA.crt -text -noout`. The output shows `CA:TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

Did you create an [Extended Validation (EV) certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate)? They are the one's that contain records other then `CN` (for example: country, city).

I had faced a similar certificate rejected error.

> This is because of extended validation, an extension we did not include in the certificate that usually requires the CA to verify the legal identification of the subject.

Source, and information on how to solve it: https://gist.github.com/Soarez/9688998#openssl-ca